# Problem with reading the data from serial port that data comes from a HC-08 module

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

Hi Everyone I have a problem with reading the data that data comes from the HC-08 Bluetooth module.

My Bluetooth module is connected to Arduino Uno like below:

> GND of module > GND of Arduino

> VCC of module > 5V of Arduino

> TX of module > RX of Arduino

> RX of module > TX of Arduino

and I connect to the module from with BLE Scanner or LightBlue Application in android.

my problem is the receiving data part in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor. My Arduino code is below:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600); //baud rate setting (9600)
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
char c=Serial.read();//read char
Serial.println(c);
delay(400);
  }
}
```

When I send the data from my android phone like below:

[image: Android Phone Send Data]

I get a response in Arduino IDE like below:

[image: Serial Monitor Response]

**like the images the data that I received is unknown and I can't see the right data how can I solve this problem? thanks.**

Comment: What arduino are you using?

Comment: I said in my question. Arduino Uno

Comment: Ah. I didn't see that. One thing to try is to add a 2K Ohm resistor between the GND and RX Pin of the module and a 1K Ohm between the RX Pin of the module and the TX Pin of the Arduino. The HC08 uses 3.3V Volts for the RX Pin while the Arduino sends 5 Volts out of the TX Pin. [See this image](https://cpl.li/assets/images/bluetooth-101_bb.png).

Comment: ok I should try thank when I try that I say here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are sending hex values and the Arduino is expecting character values.  Hex `0A` is the `<LF>` character which might be difficult for the IDE to display clearly. Try sending the hex value of `41` to see if an `A` appears in the IDE.

Some apps will allow you to change the data type to ascii or text which might make it easier to send the expected values.